# css element border influence on other elements in a weird way

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am having a weird thing I am failing to understand the cause.
I have created a [fiddle to demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/d6tukcdz/4/) the issue.

what I am failing to understand is why setting a border to one of the three canvases makes my two other .headerMainDiv go down from their original position (try to play with the border's size / delete the border and see the effect).

here is the relevant part of my html:

```
<header>
    <div class="headerMainDiv">         
        <div class="inner">         
            <canvas id="canvas1">

            </canvas>   
        </div>      
    </div>
    <div class="headerMainDiv">         
        <div class="inner">         
            <canvas id="canvas2">

            </canvas>   
        </div>      
    </div>
    <div class="headerMainDiv">
        <div class="inner">         
            <canvas id="canvas3">

            </canvas>   
        </div>      
    </div>
</header>
```

and here is the relevant css:

```
#canvas2{
  border:10px solid black;
}

.inner {
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.headerMainDiv {
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  background-color:red;
}

body{
  margin: 0;        
}

header{
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  top:0px;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: blue;
}

header div {
  display: inline-block;
}

canvas {
  background-color: grey;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

I am not looking for a solution to my problem but for an explanation to this "problem/ behavior".

Thanks a lot.
Jimmyboy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what I am failing to understand is why setting a border to one of the three canvases makes my two other .headerMainDiv go down from their original position (try to play with the border's size / delete the border and see the effect).

The issue I think you are referring to is the vertical alignment that is, be default, set to `baseline` for inline block elements...which wrap your `canvas` elements.

All you really need to do is set:

```
header div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/d6tukcdz/9/)

That said, using `border-box` is probably a good default option so I have included it in the demo.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you have used display as inline-block. The `vertical-align` property is inherited as `baseline`. That is the reason you see all the divs aligned to the floor of parent div.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Can you please detail a bit more and suggest a solution? I would like to keep it as inline-box and not float, how can I get rid of the inherited vertical-align thing? @chillvivek

Comment: use `vertical-align:top` to `.headerMainDiv`

Comment: also try `#canvas2 {
    border: 10px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}`

Answer (score 1):

That is because you have declared a 100% width on your canvas element, and added borders **on top of that**. This causes the width to exceed 100%, resulting in an overflow.

What you could do is to force the browser to compute the border width(s) as part of the width declaration. This can be done by using `box-sizing: border-box` on your canvas elements:

```css
#canvas2{
  border:10px solid black;
}

.inner {
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.headerMainDiv {
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  background-color:red;
}

body{
  margin: 0;        
}

header{
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  top:0px;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: blue;
}

header div {
  display: inline-block;
}

canvas {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Force border widths to be part of declared width */
  background-color: grey;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="headerMainDiv">         
        <div class="inner">         
            <canvas id="canvas1">

            </canvas>   
        </div>      
    </div>
    <div class="headerMainDiv">         
        <div class="inner">         
            <canvas id="canvas2">

            </canvas>   
        </div>      
    </div>
    <div class="headerMainDiv">
        <div class="inner">         
            <canvas id="canvas3">

            </canvas>   
        </div>      
    </div>
</header>
```

However, if you want to make all the divs appear to be the same height, you will need to make sure that the extra border height in the second canvas is also added to those canvases without borders, by:

1. Using top and bottom transparent borders
2. Using top and bottom margins on the first and third canvas
3. Using top and bottom paddings on the parent element of the first and third canvas

Here is a solution using the first solution:

```css
#canvas1, #canvas3 {
  border: 10px solid transparent;
}
#canvas2{
  border: 10px solid black;
}
.inner {
  margin-top: 2px;
}

.headerMainDiv {
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  background-color:red;
}

body{
  margin: 0;        
}

header{
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  top:0px;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: blue;
}

header div {
  display: inline-block;
}

canvas {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Force border widths to be part of declared width */
  background-color: grey;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="headerMainDiv">         
        <div class="inner">         
            <canvas id="canvas1">

            </canvas>   
        </div>      
    </div>
    <div class="headerMainDiv">         
        <div class="inner">         
            <canvas id="canvas2">

            </canvas>   
        </div>      
    </div>
    <div class="headerMainDiv">
        <div class="inner">         
            <canvas id="canvas3">

            </canvas>   
        </div>      
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: it did not solve it (or am I missing something?), I added *{ box-sizing: border-box} to my css and this behavior remains.

Comment: @JimmyBoy see my fiddle (in answer above)

Comment: @JimmyBoy If you mean you want equal height for all three elements, you either have to (1) declare a transparent top border or (2) declare a top margin to the canvas or (3) declare a top padding for your `.headerMainDiv` element.

Comment: I didn't see the 2nd part of your answer, it does solve it, but look at the answer i marked as answer - it **explained the cause of the problem** as well (the baseline vertical align thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you need that border doesn't affects to the width of your box, you need to specify `box-sizing` property.

```
   #canvas2{
      border:10px solid black;
      box-sizing:border-box;
   }
```

Box sizing setting to border-box avoid the paddings and the borders without affecting to your width. Check this out

http://jsfiddle.net/d6tukcdz/6/

If it's not your problem, please, explain better

Comment: My main problem is that the border affects the position of the other divs in a weird non trivial way that i would like to understand. did you see the fiddle and played with the border to see what i am talking about? @marcos

Comment: The border doesn't affect to the position. It seems as the other 2 divs are in bottom while the middle canvas is in top. This is because the `vertical-align` property. Maybe you are searching for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/d6tukcdz/11/

Comment: You should be learn to manage vertical alignments with inline-block / inline elements. you need to imagine the invisible line-height of the inline-block elements and the vertical alignment will be defined in this area (top = top line height ; baseline = base line height ; bottom = in bottom of baseline ; middle = in the middle of line height). You must to practice with that to better understand it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It's because the borders increase the width of the element. Using `box-sizing: border-box` would include the borders in the overall width of the element.

Adding `display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;` to .headerMainDiv should solve the alignment problem - updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d6tukcdz/10/).

```
canvas {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: grey;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.headerMainDiv {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 100%;
    width: 30%;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is not my problem, look in the fiddle - what i am trying to understand is why the other 2 dives are going down from their original position. this thing remains even when applying your css...

Comment: The overlapping divs in the example where the most prominent feature. I think that this edit should fix the problem.